# How to get more variables for jacobian?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to iteratively solve an equation $y'''=y''^2$ which involves finding a jacobian. I'm aware that you must have a system of equations to do this, how would i set up a jacobian for this equation alone? I know the exact solution, and i know this can be setup as $u'=u^2$ for $u=y''$. So far the only thing i came close to a system of equations was $u_1'=u_2, u_2'=u_3, u_3'=u_3^2$. Any suggestions?

Comment: What's wrong with the system of equations you have?

Comment: Using this system of equations, i get a jacobian $J
=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 1\\ 
0 & 2u_2 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$ which has no unique solution when solved in $X^{(k+1)}=X^{(k)}+JH^{(k)}$ for $H^{(0)}=J^{-1}X^{(1)}$

Comment: Uniqueness is an issue for a solution to the DE, and not just the particular Jacobian.

Comment: So is it impossible to get a jacobian for this problem? What numerical technique would you use to solve a nonlinear DE on the computer when the jacobian has no unique solution?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, why not set $u=y''$ and then your equation is $u' - u^2$.  It has solution $u(x) = \dfrac{-1}{x+c}$.  Then integrate twice to get $y$.

Alternatively, if you must use your method, I echo @Paul's comment:  What's wrong with the system you wrote?

**Edit:**  (following information in comments that was not in the Question...)

Your principal difficulty in using your Jacobian as you would like comes from having a zero vector for a column (which leads to a matrix that cannot be inverted).  This is easily avoided if you will at least change variables to $u = y'$.  Then the resulting Jacobian will be invertible.

One *can* automate this by detecting singular Jacobians, performing a singular value decomposition, and replacing the system with one of reduced dimensionality.  In this case, that process is equivalent to the substitution $u=y'$.

Comment: As I said I know the solution, i'm trying to solve for the jacobian so i can solve for the solution iteratively on the computer.

Comment: Could you show an explicit equation of such a jacobian? The euler method and the collocation method work fine for the solution numerically as they do not require inverting a jacobian. I'm just interested in solving it this way specifically since i haven't run into this case before.